# What is the best way to use Constructors in PHP

Tags: php

i have some template scripts that i want to use but i am getting this error code "PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; controller_test has a deprecated constructor in /home/wapknhmx/public_html/index.php on line 20" i have done everything ican but it's not yielding any results.
i am just a novice in php.
Please have a look at and help me. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t4tf-evxn

Comment: Rename method `controller_test` to `__construct`

Comment: There's no "best way". There's only one way. The other syntax belongs to PHP/4 and was made obsolete in 2004. It's been available for quite a while for pure backward-compatibility, but it's been removed from the language as of PHP/8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the class name as a constructor use the `__constructor` as the constructor method of your class.

For example, instead of this:

```php
class MyClass {
    public function MyClass() {
    }
}
```

use this:

```php
class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `__construct()`, not `__constructor()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: I thank each and everyone their time, i think the script is too old so the problems keeps coming, error after error.